# Jquery mobile changePage external files

Tags: jquery, animation, mobile, slide

Right now,to redirect to an other page i use:

```
document.location.href = "nextPage.html"
```

And it works fine but there aren't any animation !

So i tried :

```
$.mobile.changePage('nextPage.html','slide');
```

It works fine but then i can't use my external script !

Any idea ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

$.mobile.changePage('nextPage.html','slide');

This actually loads in the same DOM as an ajax request and you know ajax cant run script unless you write them on ajax success. So u have to call your scripts in the pageinit not document.ready. Hope you got the point.

Comment: In the "pageinit" of which page ? Because this event is never fire after $.mobile.changePage